# Android PushNotification using GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented GCM PushNotification in Android and it works perfectly fine.
I even get notifications on regular basis.
I just have one query that when I get the notifications on my device tray and if I don't click it and if other notification also appears after some time then will it show two different notifications or just one i.e latest one.

Right now I am getting only the latest one.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I got the solution to this.I was passing "0" in this method : notificationManager.notify((int) when, notification); so it was displaying the latest notification.

Comment: you mean that you can display latest one and old one both notification display?

Comment: @dipali : we can display latest as well as old ones..

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can show all notification and new one will not replace old one by passing uniqueId in **mNotificationManager.notify(uniqueId, mBuilder.build())**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setContentTitle("FleeGroups Notification")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(message))
    .setContentText(message)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(uniqueId, mBuilder.build());
```